# How to read a non-rectangular matrix into R

Tags: r, matrix, read.table

I have a large matrix of gene ID's followed by a series of bootstrap values.

For example:

> NM_001040105 1.80711736583 0.877742720548 1.0842704195 1.80711736583 0.505992862434 0.877742720548 1.37340919803 0.722846946334 1.0842704195 1.0842704195 2.52996431217 1.80711736583 1.0842704195 2.52996431217 1.80711736583 1.0842704195 1.37340919803 1.37340919803 1.0842704195 1.37340919803 0.877742720548 1.0842704195 2.52996431217 1.80711736583 1.80711736583 0.877742720548 0.877742720548 0.877742720548 1.80711736583 1.0842704195 0.722846946334 0.877742720548 0.722846946334 1.80711736583 0.877742720548 8.31273988284 1.37340919803 0.722846946334 1.0842704195 1.0842704195 1.0842704195 1.37340919803 2.52996431217 1.80711736583 1.37340919803 1.37340919803 8.31273988284 3.97565820484 1.80711736583 ...

The problem is that not every gene has the same amount of bootstrap values, so the matrix is not rectangular, thus read.table() won't work. readLines() won't necessarily work either, as I need the gene IDs to be associated with their respective bootstrap values. Is there any way to read a table like this into R?

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Have you tried  `read.table(..., fill = TRUE)`?

Comment: Why wont readLines work? I'm assuming each gene is in a separate line and you've only added lines breaks for clarity. If not, what separates gene values. After you read your data in should just be able to split and save in a list.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
#sample data
test<-c("NM_001040105 1.80711736583 0.877742720548 1.0842704195",
"PR_00104145 0.722846946334", 
"QQ_001678941 1.37340919803 0.877742720548 1.0842704195 2.52996431217 1.80711736583 1.80711736583 0.877742720548")
```

Here I use a textConnection to read in the sample data, but you should just be able to pass a filename to readLines as well. I also split the data right away on spaces

```
con<-textConnection(test)
nn<-strsplit(readLines(con), " ")
close(con)
```

Now i turn it into a list and make the values numeric. I use the first element as the name, and all the rest as the values.

```
Map(function(a,b)b, sapply(nn,"[",1), 
    lapply(nn,function(x) as.numeric(tail(x,-1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably performant way, assuming `test` is the result of `readLines()`:

```
space <- regexpr(" ", test, fixed=TRUE)
id <- substring(test, 1L, space-1L)
setNames(strsplit(substring(test, space+1L), " ", fixed=TRUE), id)
```