# Importing non-rectangular data as rectangular in R

Tags: r, social-networking

I need to load social network data where each user has an unknown and potentially large number of friends, stored as a text file of the following format:

```
UserId: FriendId1, FriendId2, ...
1: 12, 33
2:
3: 4, 6, 10, 15, 16
```

into a two-column data.frame:

```
  UserId FriendId
1      1       12
2      1       33
3      3        4
4      3        6
5      3       10
6      3       15
7      3       16
```

How would you do that in R?

Reading, filling and then reshaping is inefficient as it requires to keep in memory many columns full of `NA`.

Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091275/how-to-read-a-non-rectangular-matrix-into-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016817/importing-and-analysing-non-rectangular-csv-files-in-r).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really have a colon as a delimiter, then just use `read.table` with `header = FALSE` to get your data into R, then consider using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

```
mydf <- read.table("test.txt", sep = ":", header = FALSE)
mydf
##   V1                V2
## 1  1            12, 33
## 2  2                  
## 3  3  4, 6, 10, 15, 16

library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, "V2", ",", "long")
##    V1 V2
## 1:  1 12
## 2:  1 33
## 3:  3  4
## 4:  3  6
## 5:  3 10
## 6:  3 15
## 7:  3 16
```

Answer (score 3):

This reads the lines, then one-by-one parses them into two column matrices. This does produce character values (since lines of text are just characters) but it's trivial to coerce to numeric:

```
 do.call(rbind,  sapply(rLines, function(L) { n <- sub( ":.+", "", L);
         items <- scan(text=sub(".+:","",L), sep=",");
     matrix( c( rep(n, length(items)), items), ncol=2)}
                        )
           )
#---------
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "12"
[2,] "1"  "33"
[3,] "3"  "4" 
[4,] "3"  "6" 
[5,] "3"  "10"
[6,] "3"  "15"
[7,] "3"  "16"
```

If the path forward isn't trivial to you then educate yourself at `?as.numeric` and `?as.data.frame`.